# How to make prediction on new text dataset using saved text classification model

Tags: python, keras, nlp, text-classification

I trained a text classifier under this guide: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-4

And save model as

```
model.save('~./output/model.h5')
```

In this case, how i use this model to classify texts on another new dataset?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Recreate the exact same model, including its weights and the optimizer
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('~./output/model.h5')

# Show the model architecture
new_model.summary()

# Apply the same process of data preparation while training the model.
# Lets say after Data preprocessing you have stored the processed data in test_data

# check model accuracy from unseen/new dataset
loss, acc = new_model.evaluate(test_data,  test_labels, verbose=2)
print('Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%'.format(100*acc))
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about how i should handle the new test data's text vectorize and embedding part when i want to use saved model?

Comment: Re-iterate the test data  throught the same process which you have done before training the model - as simple as that.

Comment: It has error:Input Source operations connected to node sequential_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup/633 (defined at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py:112)
Function call stack:
predict_function

Comment: Share the proper code and details to understand the error.

Comment: I have post a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64351963/how-to-deal-with-unseen-tokens-in-test-dataset

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the tensorflow's Text tokenization utility class (Tokenizer) to deal with unknown words in Test data.**

1. Num_words is the vocabulary size (it picks most frequent words)
2. Assign oov_token = 'Some string', used for all the tokens/words outside vocab size (basically new words in test data will be dealt as oov_token string .
3. Fit on Train data and then generate token sequence for both train and test data.

   tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(
   num_words=None, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\t\n', lower=True,
   split=' ', char_level=False, oov_token=None, document_count=0, **kwargs
   )